# Add column to dataframe if file exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I would like to add new columns if a file exists.

This is my approach:

```
files = 'input/'
if files.endswith('txt') and 'text' in files:
    df['A'] = 'blah'
    df['B'] = 'Test'
    df['C'] = 'Test2'
else:
    pass
```

but there's nothing added to "`df`". What's the problem?

Edit:
Thx to Aravind G. this is the solution:

```
files = 'input/'
data = [x for x in os.listdir(files) if x .endswith('txt') and 'text' in x]
if len(data) > 0:
   df['A'] = 'blah'
   df['B'] = 'Test'
   df['C'] = 'Test2'
else:
   pass
```

Answer (score 1):

`files` is a string defined by you, which *does not* end with `'txt'`. That's why it never adds anything to `df`.

To check if a file with given filename exists, you could use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

If you want to check if a file exists in the given directory with given specifications, you could simply do this -

```
files_list = [f for f in glob('input/*') if 'text' in f]
if len(files_list) > 0:
    df['A'] = 'blah'
    df['B'] = 'Test'
    df['C'] = 'Test2'
else:
    pass
```

Comment: Thx, but this didn't work, but you gave the correct hint. I edited the post with the solution.